# having an issue with my jquery responsive webpage

Tags: jquery

I am building a responsive webpage and so far i have some of it functioning. however there is one aspect i cannot seem to do
i would like to use jquery to move my vertical menu that is on the left of the page by -280px left (off the page) therefore the 
entire content of the page will be shown. this should only happen when a submenu link is clicked and return it when a link at the top of the page is clicked.
I hope I have described this clearly. how would i go about writing such a script?

```
HTML
 <nav class="pushmenu-left">

                <div id="caption"><h1>Mobile</h1></div>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#tab-1">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tab-2">Support</a></li>
                    <li class="active"><a href="#tab-3">Web Design</a>

                        <ul>
                          <li><a href="#tab-4">HTML</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#tab-5">CSS</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#tab-6">JavaScript</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#tab-7">Content Management</a>

                        <ul>
                          <li><a href="#tab-8">Joomla</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#tab-9">Drupal</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#tab-10">WordPress</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#tab-11">Concrete 5</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li><a href="#tab-12">Contact</a>

                        <ul>

                          <li><a href="#tab-13">General Inquiries</a></li>

                          <li><a href="#tab-14">Ask A Question</a></li>

                        </ul>

                      </li>

                    <li><a href="#tab-15">About</a></li>

                </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this library: http://www.berriart.com/sidr/

Or if you don't need any animations and want to build it by hand, try something like this:

```
$("#id-of-submenu-link-that-hides-menu").on('click',function() {
    var menu = $('#id-of-menu-to-hide');
    menu.css('position','absolute');//if you have it positioned some other way
    menu.css('margin-left','-280px');
});

$("#id-of-link-to-show-menu").on('click',function() {
    var menu = $('#id-of-menu-to-hide');
    menu.css('position','inherit');//or whatever it originally was
    menu.css('margin-left','0');
});
```

You may or may not need to mess with the position of the menu - it just depends on how you currently have it positioned. Try it with and without that positioning change if you're not sure.

Hope that helps. Let me know if you any of it doesn't make sense and good luck!

Comment: i tries it but it did not work. thi most important thing i would like to achieve is to be able to click on a sub menu link and have the entire vertical menu block slide off the page to the left exposing the content of the link that was clicked.

Comment: Yeah my code will just make it appear and disappear, not slide. I just edited my post to add a jquery plugin that does what you need.